# PrestaShop - Changing carrier list depending on product attributes

Tags: prestashop, cart, product, carrier

i need to change some carrier list when product has some category id. Where should I start to achieve that. I thought about adding some global variable and modify Cart.php & Carriers.php. Or maybe the correct approach is by hooking beforeCarrier?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?
In theory, there are two options 
1. Assign to each product, available carrier (table product_carrier) and in that way you can control for each product which carriers are available. I dont like this solution, to many rows in database... Anyway you can check this module by NemoPS http://store.nemops.com/free-modules/43-carrier-assigner-free-module.html#.XKStbZgzaCo

2. Override cart checkout to exclude carriers from selection if your conditions meet.

I will work on it and I will let you know for my solution.